# Hidden content not resizing within UIStackView in Swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, resize, hidden, uistackview

I have made an app with a horizontal scrollable menu which reveals information below, depending on which button is clicked. As the labels are variable in size I have placed them all within a vertical UIStackView, which is layered on a vertical scroll view. I then set the labels in the stack view to hidden or visible depending on the button pressed. I've read that a stack view is supposed to resize automatically, removing the empty space, but this does not happen. However, if I click the same button again the content appropriately resizes:

[After first click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X07Gu.png)
[After second click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsy0H.png)

I have tried multiple variants, where I reveal all the content of the stack view before hiding the labels not required, and vice versa, as well as individually hiding or revealing each label in turn, but nothing seems to solve this. The latest code I've used is below. I'd be really grateful if anyone can help?

Thanks

```
@IBAction func test1Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    hideAllInfo ()
    label1.hidden = false
}

@IBAction func test2Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    hideAllInfo ()
    label2.hidden = false
    label3.hidden = false
}

func hideAllInfo () {
    label1.hidden = true
    label2.hidden = true
    label3.hidden = true
    label4.hidden = true
    label5.hidden = true
    label6.hidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to find the solution. For some reason revealing multiple hidden variables at the same time causes problems with auto-layout. I managed to rectify it by placing all the revealed contents in a further separate stack view so only one item was revealed at a time.